# Should I avoid reference to pointer in modern C++ or it is okay in this special case

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, c++17

I'm aware that raw pointers (or more accurately `new` and `delete`)  in modern C++ must be avoided unless really needed. I believe when it comes to graph implementation, pointers are pretty useful. I'd be happy to hear comments on this though.

I'm playing around with Binary Search Trees and writing `insert` functions. I implemented using two different but similar methods, one using pointer and the other one using reference to pointer. Clearly I would like to change the the pointer itself (ref to ptr). Wondering if any of them has advantages or either should not be used and must be written using const reference or smart pointer (modern way).

```
Node *insert_ptr(Node *root, int data)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return create(data);
    else if (data < root->data)
        root->left = insert(root->left, data);
    else
        root->right = insert(root->right, data);
    return root;
}

void insert_ref_to_ptr(Node *&root, int data)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        root = create(data);
    else if (data < root->data)
        insert(root->left, data);
    else
        insert(root->right, data);
}
```

I'm providing the rest of code below if you want to get a run. You may want to use `1 3 6 8 10 14 13 4 7` as input

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

void display(Node *root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        display(root->left);
        cout << root->data << " ";
        display(root->right);
    }
}

Node *create(int data)
{
    Node *node = new Node();
    node->data = data;
    node->left = node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}

int main()
{
    Node *root = NULL;
    vector<int> nodes;

    string line;
    int value;
    getline(cin, line);
    stringstream split(line);
    while (split >> value)
        nodes.push_back(value);
    /*
    root = insert_ptr(root, nodes[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < nodes.size(); i++)
        insert_ptr(root, nodes[i]);
    */

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++)
        insert_ref_to_ptr(root, nodes[i]);
    display(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Definitely not a good design. All these functions should be in the class, and left and right should be unique pointers.

Comment: You should definitely avoid using raw pointers at all, unless you're a 100% sure you'll need them.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Definitely right. But I'm not concerned with the design here.

Comment: What's the point then of this question?

Comment: Are you asking about binary trees, encapsulation, or good c++ practices? If you want new/delete, you must fully encapsulate it. You have no reason to do new/delete here, though.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher  `Wondering if any of them has advantages or either should not be used and must be written using const reference or smart pointer (modern way).`

Comment: @KennyOstrom interesting point. How would you do it without `new/delete` or `shared_ptr`.

Comment: You don't have a proper understanding of C++. Raw pointers are useful to pass non-managed objects. That's it. That's what they are for. And you use make_unique or make_shared to create your objects.

Comment: Probably like this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert Do you have any use cases not already covered in the standard library?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I absolutely do not. I can tell you have a great understanding of C++ but not being helpful yet aggressive to a beginner. I did my ultimate effort. Thanks sir.

Comment: The specific reason your code does not meet modern practices is the use of new and delete (acceptable only if hidden inside a well encapsulated class).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`that pointers in modern C++ must be avoided unless really needed`  that's wrong.

`new` and `delete` should be avoided and you should use unique and shared pointers instead.

But you will still pass an object by reference or raw pointer if you don't transfer ownership.

Your `Node` has an ownership relation so it should be:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> left;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> right;
};
```

or

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> left;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> right;
};
```

Your `display` function does not need ownership, so you pass the node as pointer (or reference)

```
void display(Node *root)
{
    if (root != nullptr)
    {
        display(root->left);
        cout << root->data << " ";
        display(root->right);
    }
}
```

As you don't plan to change it I would go with const ref:

```
void display(const Node &root)
{
    if(root.left != nullptr) {
        display(*root.left);
    }

    cout << root.data << " ";

    if(root.right != nullptr) {
        display(*root.right);
    }
}
```

You `insert_ref_to_ptr` is a really bad construct, because it is not clear that it transferes any ownership and as is not clear that it calls `create(data)` inside which create a Node using `new`.

The create would look something like that:

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> create(int data)
{
    auto node = std::make_unique<Node>();
    node->data = data;
    return std::move(node);
}
```

And the `insert_ref_to_ptr` function something like that:

```
void insert_ref_to_ptr(std::unique_ptr<Node> &root, int data)
{
    if (root == nullptr)
        root = std::move(create(data));
    else if (data < root->data)
        insert(root->left, data);
    else
        insert(root->right, data);
}
```

Comment: How would your own `insert` function look like then?

Comment: Very interested to see how you would implement the whole thing. It'd be very educational and helpful if you can do so.

Comment: @KarimSole How I would implement that tree, depends on the use-case. But your question was more about if pointers, and references and references to pointers should still be used. And yes the should, but it is always important what you do with it. I would recommend you to take a look a talk [“Leak-Freedom in C++... By Default.” of Herb Sutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE) (or any other talk of him or Titus Winter)

Comment: Sure sir. For my specific case, I'm so interested to see how an experienced developer will right for this simple use-case. Would you please put an effort on the last part. Highly appreciated.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something, or is it wrong for `display` to take by reference here? The usual pattern with tree structures is for leaf nodes to have `left` and `right` as `nullptr`, in which case the dereferencing necessary in `display` will invoke UB. (The `root != NULL` check also doesn't make a lot sense.)

Comment: @N.Shead you are right, the `nullptr` check has to be done before dereferencing the `unique_ptr`. I was sure that I had updated that, thx for the comment.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm aware that pointers in modern C++ must be avoided unless really needed.

That is not true. What you probably heard is that you should avoid raw (naked) pointers if your requirements fit an standardized pattern/solution, like `unique_ptr`.

> Clearly I would like to change the the pointer itself (ref to ptr). Wondering if any of them has advantages or either should not be used and must be written using const reference (modern way).

If you want to have output parameters, you have quite some ways to do it:

- Return value.
- Reference to value (as parameter).
- Pointer to value (as parameter).
- Several return values in a `struct`, `std::tuple` or using structured bindings.
- Member variable (only for member functions in classes).
- Global variable.

There is not a single best way for all cases. Which one you use is up to you and how you are going to use the function. In some cases, it also depends on the coding style guidelines of the projects (e.g. in the case of reference vs. pointer). For instance:

- Some people prefer to use a return value if there is only a single output parameter.
- Some libraries prefer to use return values exclusively for error codes.
- Some coding style guidelines avoid references because they want to see explicitly in the caller that you are passing an address (e.g. `f(a)` vs. `f(&a)`).
- In member functions you usually employ the member variables.
- In almost all cases you should avoid global variables for this purpose.

---

> must be written using const reference (modern way).

By the way, note that you didn't write a `const` reference, just a reference to `Note *`. And it is not "modern C++": references were a part of the first C++ standard.

Comment: There is no preference or best practice basically?!

Comment: For the general case, no, not really.

Comment: Very helpful indeed. If you would have a chance to write `insert` function using your own style, I'd be very thrilled. So curious how an expert will write such cases.

Comment: @KarimSole In C, probably your first interface would be the most popular solution (returning the pointer). In C++, almost everyone would design a class to encapsulate the data structure (see the standard C++ library for examples of this) — therefore, `insert` would be a member function.